# PHP - Adding predefined text as well as session variable using fwrite

Tags: php, session, variables, printf

In the following code, i want to be able to include 'Name:', 'Age:' and 'Email:' before the PHP script writes the variables $name, $age and $email.

It seems so simple, but i just can't get it to work!

```
<?php

session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['name']; 
$age = $_SESSION['age'];
$email =  $_SESSION['email'];

$handle = fopen('users.txt', 'a');
fwrite($handle, $name."\n"); 

$handle = fopen('users.txt', 'a');
fwrite($handle, $age."\n"); 

$handle = fopen('users.txt', 'a');
fwrite($handle, $email."\n"); 

fclose($handle); 

?>
```

I have tried this:

```
<?php

session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['name']; 
$age = $_SESSION['age'];
$email =  $_SESSION['email'];

$handle = fopen('users.txt', 'a');
fwrite($handle, 'Name:', $name."\n"); 

$handle = fopen('users.txt', 'a');
fwrite($handle, 'Age:', $age."\n"); 

$handle = fopen('users.txt', 'a');
fwrite($handle, 'Email', $email."\n"); 

fclose($handle); 

?>
```

However, all that prints in the user.txt document is 'Age:'.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE: Removed the multiple fopen and replaced ',' with '.' Everything working perfectly, thanks for everyones help!**

Comment: Why do you use multiple `fopen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use this

```
$fp = fopen('users.txt', 'a');

fwrite($fp, 'Name : '.$name . PHP_EOL);
fwrite($fp, 'Age : '.$age . PHP_EOL);
fwrite($fp, 'Email : '.$email . PHP_EOL);

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Wow, like i thought, so simple! 

Thanks for your help, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

session_start();

$data = array(
    'Name:'  . (isset($_SESSION['name'])  ? $_SESSION['name']  : '') ,
    'Age:'   . (isset($_SESSION['age'])   ? $_SESSION['age']   : '') ,
    'Email:' . (isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] ; '') ,
);

if ($fp = fopen('users.txt','a')) {
    fwrite($fp,implode(PHP_EOL,$data).PHP_EOL); 
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    die('Error');
}
```